# How do I get Excel to interact with my website?

Tags: excel, web

I want to use Excel 2010 to do calculations from my personal website. I would like for the user to enter data in a field and press submit. Then, Excel takes the data, performs calculations on it, and outputs the calculated data into another field form that the user can see.

This needs to be done away from the actual website because I don't want to share the formulas on Excel.

For example:

A web page has three fields: First digit, second digit, and solution.  The end user enters 2 and 5 into the first and second forms and Press submit. An Excel sheet adds these numbers in the background. The number 7 appears in the solution field.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think you mean fields instead of forms? How does Excel "take that data?" Or is that what the question is asking, "How do I get Excel to interact with my web site?"

Comment: I believe so. That is a much better way to rephrase my question. Sorry for the lack of clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You say this is on your personal website, so I assume you have access to the server and can do some rudimentary scripting. Is it absolutely necessary to use Excel? This seems like it would be more straightforward to employ perl, PHP, python, etc. to perform simple addition.

If you did the calculations in Javascript, you would be exposing the formulas to viewers, as the client executes the script and therefore must have the source code.

However, with one of the aforementioned scripting languages, the source of the script is parsed by the server but never passed to the user.

For example, a php script could simply send the results of a form submit to itself:

Areas between `<?php` and `?>` are parsed server-side and never passed to the user.

```
<?php
    $a = '';
    $b = '';
    $result = '';

    if (@$_POST['submit'] == 'Submit')
    {
        $a = $_POST['a'];
        $b = $_POST['b'];
        $result = SecretFormula($a, $b);
    }

    function SecretFormula($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" method="post" action="">
            Enter Number A: <input name="a" type="text" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" /><br />
            Enter Number B: <input name="b" type="text" value="<?php echo $b; ?>" /><br />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
            <br />
            Result: <input name="result" type="text" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to use Excel, but it does need to be a spreadsheet application like Excel, Access, etc.  The reason being that the formula gets updated every so often. However, there is always X number of inputs and one output. So I should be able to import the data and export the solution back to the page from known cells.

Comment: Thanks for the input tho. Reading through your code helped me polish up on html/php formats that I may have to use. :)

Comment: Hmm. I have never heard of using Excel as a backend for a live web page. My only recommendation might be to use Excel to generate the formulas you need, and have a script read it in from the Excel file itself or something that your formula maintainer copies to the server.

Comment: Okay. I was afraid that it couldn't be done. Oh well, I'll put some thought and research into your solution and see what I can come up with. Thank you!

Comment: Just to help out any readers in the future, there is a up and coming project called PHPExcel.  It uses PHP to create, write, and read from excel files and allows you to interface it with HTML. I believe this is what I need to solve my problem. I have only dipped my toes in the research, tho.